# AccessDecisionManager, how to add RoleVoter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

First of all I would like to ask, if it is possible to access default `AccessDecisionManager` within Java Configuration (without using any xml file)?

Secondary, my problem looks like that. I want to add `RoleVoter` to my configuration, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

   ...

   @Bean
   public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
      RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
      roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ADMIN > USER");
      return roleHierarchy;
   }

   @Bean
   public RoleHierarchyVoter roleHierarchyVoter(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy){
      return new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy);
   }
```

My attempt was to add my `AffirmativeBased` manager bean to `HttpSecurity` by `authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(defaultAccessDecisionManager)`.

```
@Bean
public AffirmativeBased defaultAccessDecisionManager(RoleVoter roleVoter, AuthenticatedVoter authenticatedVoter, PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter preAdviceVoter){
    AffirmativeBased affirmativeBased = new AffirmativeBased(Arrays.asList(new WebExpressionVoter,(AccessDecisionVoter) roleVoter));
    affirmativeBased.setAllowIfAllAbstainDecisions(true);
    return affirmativeBased;
}
```

But it fails when comming to vote, because of `WebExpressionConfigAttribute` class which always return null on `getAttribute` method.

**EDIT:** I think I figured it out. My attemp was'nt so wrong, here little edit of `defaultAccessDecisionManager`

```
@Bean
public AffirmativeBased defaultAccessDecisionManager(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy){
    WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter = new WebExpressionVoter();
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
    webExpressionVoter.setExpressionHandler(expressionHandler);
    return new AffirmativeBased(Arrays.asList((AccessDecisionVoter) webExpressionVoter));
}
```

But still, I must add this `defaultAccessDecisionManager` to every `HttpSecurity` object in configurations. Anyone know how to do it globally?

Comment: That all looks like it would work. Wouldn't it be simpler to create an expression handler, add your `RoleHierarchy`, and then inject it into the chain through `http.authorizeRequests().expressionHandler(...)`? I don't think there's such a thing as a global default (could be wrong).

Answer (score 2):

```
http
.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/**")
.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/only").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<AffirmativeBased>() {
        @Override
        public AffirmativeBased postProcess(AffirmativeBased affirmativeBased) {
            affirmativeBased.getDecisionVoters().add(0, myAccessDecisionVoter1()); // add before WebExpressionVoter
            affirmativeBased.getDecisionVoters().add(myAccessDecisionVoter2()); // add after WebExpressionVoter
            return affirmativeBased;
        }
    });
```